# Rails ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber not outputting verbose query logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to enable [verbose query logging](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs) in Rails, but the `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber` is behaving oddly, which is causing the verbose query logging to not work.

The issue seems to be originating here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L113

If I `inspect` the `locations` variable, I can see that it *does* have content:

```
[
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:100:in `debug'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:45:in `sql'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:145:in `finish'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:107:in `finish'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:160:in `finish'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:62:in `block in finish'",
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:62:in `each'",
  ...
]
```

But once it's gone through the `clean` method, it's an empty array. So this:

```rb
backtrace_cleaner.clean(locations.lazy).first
```

is returning `nil`. Therefore, the `source` assignment on [line 105](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L105) is `nil`, which means the `if source` on [line 107](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L107) evaluates to false, and doesn't log anything.

---

### UPDATE

I've added these two `puts` into `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber`:

```rb
def log_query_source
  source = extract_query_source_location(caller)

  puts "-----\n-\n-\nCALLERS: #{caller.inspect}\n-\n-\n-----"

  if source
    logger.debug("  ↳ #{source}")
  end
end

def extract_query_source_location(locations)
  puts "-----\n-\n-\nCLEANER: #{backtrace_cleaner.instance_values}\n-\n-\n-----"

  backtrace_cleaner.clean(locations.lazy).first
end
```

to help gather some context about what's actually being registered as a caller and what the backtrace cleaner has established for filtering and silencing.

Here's the output for callers (I'm just including enough to show that there are sources listed from within our application):

```
[
  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:100:in `debug'",
  
  ...

  "/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/api/app/graph/api/loaders/association_loader.rb:47:in `preload_association'",
  "/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/api/app/graph/api/loaders/association_loader.rb:34:in `perform'",

  ...

  "/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/api/app/controllers/api/graphql_controller.rb:16:in `execute'",

  ...

  "/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/api/lib/api/graphql_reloader.rb:18:in `call'",

  ...

  "/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-5.6.5/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'"
]
```

And here's the output for the backtrace cleaner:

```
{
  "silencers"=>[
    #<Proc:0x0000000108343330@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb:101>, 
    #<Proc:0x00000001083432e0@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb:105>, 
    #<Proc:0x00000001083431c8@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:19>
  ], 
  "filters"=>[
    #<Proc:0x0000000108343380@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb:97>, 
    #<Proc:0x0000000108343240@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:16>, 
    #<Proc:0x0000000108343218@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:17>, 
    #<Proc:0x00000001083431f0@/Users/jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:18>
  ], 
  "root"=>"/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/"
}
```

As you can see, nothing specific to our application code is being silenced (or even filtered). However, there is that `"root"` instance value, which is very odd because if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb) for `ActiveRecord::BacktraceCleaner`, the only instance variables that are defined are `@filters` and `@silencers`.

I'm guessing that that's involved here, since the path set as the value of `"root"` would be removing our application-level traces (if being used as a silencer). The problem is that I have no idea where that's coming from.

The only thing I could guess is that one of our gems is overloading `ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner` to add the `@root` instance variable and some additional layer of silencing based on that. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: remove filters/silencers, to check if any of them cause an issue: `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!`  `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.backtrace_cleaner.remove_filters!`. also this should just always log something, even in a console: `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.new.send(:log_query_source)`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html

Comment: @Alex Updated the question with some additional findings related to your comment.

Comment: That seems right, it's the last caller which is usually silenced. i guess you should take a look at what `clean` method does. and check if there are any extra unwanted filters/silencers, i only have the ones definded in two `backtrace_cleaner.rb` files, 4 filters, 3 silencers. and apparently it's just `Rails.backtrace_cleaner`

Comment: @Alex I just added another update.

Comment: `@root` is from here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb. i can't imagine it's a regex issue. there are also `Gem.path` and `Gem.default_dir` that could affect things.

Comment: @Alex Ahhh, thank you! That's one mystery solved. :-)

So the `add_filter`s would be fine, and those totally make sense, and means that `@root` is not the issue.

As for the silencer – `add_silencer { |line| !APP_DIRS_PATTERN.match?(line) }` – correct me if I'm wrong, but that should only be removing lines that *don't* contain "app", "config", "lib", or "test", right?

Comment: i guess it is a regex issue. i assume `/components/api` is an engine so it wouldn't match anything. what if you just move it to your `lib` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Rails Console Always Disables Verbose Logging

Are you testing verbose logging by looking at what the Rails server is logging or by looking at activity in the Rails console?  [This line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L62) will always turn off verbose query logging for activity performed in the console:

```rb
# ActiveRecord::Railtie
console do |app|
  require "active_record/railties/console_sandbox" if app.sandbox?
  require "active_record/base"
  unless ActiveSupport::Logger.logger_outputs_to?(Rails.logger, STDERR, STDOUT)
    console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDERR)
    Rails.logger.extend ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast console
  end
  ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = false  # <--- HERE
end
```

[Here's the commit that added that line](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1044e8b355930e8cb14d1f182d33a561fdaca65b).  The commit message provides more details and refers back to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31688).  This is intentional and was done to reduce noise in the Rails console.

If you want to turn verbose logging back on in the Rails console, you would have to manually reset the flag with:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
```

Or you could add this in an initializer in your app to turn it on whenever the console boots:

```rb
# config/initializers/verbose_logging.rb
Rails.application.console do
  ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true
end
```

Note that the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs) suggests not turning this on in Production because of the memory usage, so you may want to keep it off in that environment depending upon the resources available where you run your Production console.

#### The Backtrace is Cleaned Before Logging

When the verbose logging is made, Rails will attempt to drop out standard Ruby code references and gem reference so that the source location within the app is displayed.  This is done using the cleaner in `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.backtrace_cleaner` which by default is the [`Rails::BacktraceCleaner`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb) which inherits from the [`ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb).

To test if the `Rails::BacktraceCleaner` is accidentally cleaning out your code you could do something like this:

```rb
# Get the source location for a class method somewhere in your app
path = MyClass.method(:my_class_method).source_location.first

# Run it through the BacktraceCleaner
backtrace_cleaner = Rails::BacktraceCleaner.new
backtrace_cleaner.clean([path])
```

If that returns `[]` you might want to check to see if you put your app code in the `RbConfig::CONFIG["rubylibdir"]` folder.  The BacktraceCleaner will assume that code there is a part of the standard Ruby library and will remove it from the backtrace.

The `Rails::BacktraceCleaner` also excludes code that isn't found in the `app`, `config`, `lib`, or `test` subdirectories.  That's done [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L19).

Your `root` says it is:

```
/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/
```

And then the subfolder beneath that is:

```
/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/...
```

Rails will clean that out of the backtrace.  You can check with something like:

```
test = ['/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple/components/api/app/graph/api/loaders/association_loader.rb']
backtrace_cleaner = Rails::BacktraceCleaner.new

# Filtering will drop off everything before the root
filtered = backtrace_cleaner.send(:filter_backtrace, [path])
 => ["components/api/app/graph/api/loaders/association_loader.rb"]

# Silencing will drop off paths that don't start with app, config, lib, or test
backtrace_cleaner.send(:silence, filtered)
 => []
```

To avoid this you could:

- Organize your code into different subfolders, or
- Override `Rails::BacktraceCleaner`, or
- Redefine `Rails::BacktraceCleaner::APP_DIRS_PATTERN` in an initializer

The last option would be the easiest but will throw `already initialized constant` errors when the app boots.

Comment: I'm referring only to the server output.

Comment: Did you happen to put your app directly within the standard Ruby folder?  I added an example of something you could try to see if the BacktraceCleaner is removing your app code paths from the backtrace.

Comment: Nope, the app lives here: `/Users/jeff/Development/lead-simple/LeadSimple`. However, I've added some more context to my question in light of some things you brought up, as it could definitely be related.

Comment: Thanks @cschroed! This was exactly what I needed and I've gone with the last option. I'm not a big fan of it since, as you mentioned, it throws a lot of warnings when the app boots, but it's definitely the "lightest" approach in that I don't have to monkey-patch the entire `Rails::BacktraceCleaner`. I've provided my own answer as well just to show folks exactly how I implemented this, but I've accepted and upvoted your answer as it's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cschroed for his answer that gave me what I needed.

Just wanted to post my own answer as well to show how I fully implemented this:

`config/initializers/verbose_sql_logging.rb`

```rb
if Rails.env.development? && ENV['VERBOSE_SQL_LOGGING']&.downcase == 'true'
  # NOTE: As of Rails 7, this will need to be set using `ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs=`.
  ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true

  # NOTE: This is required because of our `components/` directory. By default, Rails will silence
  # any path that doesn't start with "app", "config", "lib", or "test".
  #
  # Reference:
  #   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L7
  #   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L19
  Rails::BacktraceCleaner::APP_DIRS_PATTERN = Regexp.new(
    Rails::BacktraceCleaner::APP_DIRS_PATTERN.to_s.gsub('app|', 'app|components|')
  )

  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stdout)
end
```

The reason I did a `gsub` to inject the `components` directory into the regex pattern instead of just reassigning the constant to a different regex literal is because the pattern is slightly different in Rails 7 (compared to what we're currently on – Rails 6.0.0).

**Rails 6.0.0:** https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L7

**Rails 7:** https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb#L8

As you can see, the basic logic is still the same, which will allow the `gsub` to continue to work properly, but I'm assuming the logic is just a bit tighter. And by modifying what Rails already has defined, instead of reassigning from scratch, it means we'll be able to take advantage of this update to the regex pattern if/when we upgrade to Rails 7 without having to modify our initializer.